# Dropbox Family plan alternative

Tags: cloud-service, cloud-storage, cloud, dropbox

I'm looking for an alternative to the `Dropbox Family` plan, because it has a hard upper limit of 2TB.

The alternative should have more than 2TB and offer the following functionalities from Dropbox Family:

- One account pays the cloud storage bills. Family members can then make their own account and join the family account for free.
- There's a joined space accessible to all.
- Each family member can also have its own private space.
- The software should be integrated in Windows. Android integration would be a plus.
- The user interface should be simple. Some of my family members are not tech savvy.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This doesn't do everything you want, but idrive.com has a 10TB plan for $150/year, possibly discounted first year. I'm not crazy about it, but it does work and is fairly inexpensive

Comment: I don't find a "family plan" on their website. That means every family member would have to purchase his/her own account?

Comment: Or you'd have to share the 10TB; I admit it's not ideal, just a thought. You might consider a Dropbox Business plan (https://www.dropbox.com/business/plans-comparison) but they appear to be fairly expensive

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using a hardware solution. I am using a Synology NAS box at home. You can get it in lots of configurations and sizes snd put in the drives you want, in a RAID configuration.

Then you can make spaces for each login. Each folder has read, write etc permissions that you can give to other users, or not. Each folder can also be encrypted so the admin can't access the folders either.

You dont need a static IP, it has built in dyndns style support.

Its apps are amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [365 Family plan](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/onedrive/compare-onedrive-plans?activetab=tab:primaryr1) caters for up to 6 people, and a single payer;  each gets 1TB of storage. It's USD100/year, and is well-integrated with Windows (ie also just Windows Explorer)

I'm not 100% sure how simple setting up sharing between people is. You don't have to use to email or other functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I am using free and open source Syncthing (https://syncthing.net/) for keeping files synchronised files across many devices.

This is not cloud based, so not exactly like Dropbox.

But it's really only limited by how much space you have on your drive.